# How to get the value of String in RichText Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, richtext, flutter-text

How to get the value of String in `RichText` Widget.

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Woolha ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
      TextSpan(text: 'dot '),
      TextSpan(
          text: 'com',
          style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline))
    ],
  ),
  textScaleFactor: 0.5,
)
```

I want to get the value of String in `RichText`, does anyone have a way to do it?

Comment: I want to get the value of String in richText, does anyone have a way to do it, please help me (((:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use key to extract text from `RichText`.

```dart
final RichText? richText = richTextKey.currentWidget as RichText?;

debugPrint("${richText?.text.toPlainText()}");
```

```dart
class GettingRichText extends StatelessWidget {
  GettingRichText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final richTextKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RichText(
        key: richTextKey,
        text: const TextSpan(
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: 'Woolha ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
            TextSpan(text: 'dot '),
            TextSpan(
                text: 'com',
                style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline))
          ],
        ),
        textScaleFactor: 0.5,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final RichText? richText = richTextKey.currentWidget as RichText;

          debugPrint("${richText?.text.toPlainText()}");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you out. you can check more about [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can provide String variable on `text` property of `TextSpan` something like below.

```
String myText = "dot";

TextSpan(text: myText),
```

Comment: thank you but this is not what i want

Comment: oh I took your question wrong